# Packging LEFT and RIGHT channel data

Tags: c++, audio, openal, flac

I am decoding FLAC audio into memory, and passing the decoded audio data to the OpenAL: `void alBufferData (ALuint bufferName, ALenum format, const ALvoid *data, ALsizei size, ALsizei frequency);`

The data from the decoded audio goes into mine `std::vector<FLAC__int32> data_;`. Into which I am attempting to package the LEFT and RIGHT channels (AL_FORMAT_STEREO16). However, I don't understand how I am to store/align these channels within my `data_` vector.

So I have the libFLAC virtual callback member function:

```
FLAC__StreamDecoderWriteStatus
Source::write_callback (
    FLAC__Frame const* _frame, FLAC__int32 const *const _buffer[])
{

    for(size_t i(0); i < _frame->header.blocksize; i++) {

        data_[index_] = _buffer[0][i]; // channel audio on the left
        ++index_;

        data_[index_] = _buffer[1][i]; // what about the right channel?

    } // jump

    return FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_WRITE_STATUS_CONTINUE;
} // main
```

At the moment, during audio playback, I am hearing only the LEFT channel. There is static sound after the sound has finished playing which I am assuming is the missing RIGHT channel data. How do i get the RIGHT channel to work also?

Also, this is the metadata callback signature as per libFLAC:

```
void
Source::metadata_callback (const ::FLAC__StreamMetadata *metadata)
{

    total_samples_ = metadata->data.stream_info.total_samples;
    rate_ = metadata->data.stream_info.sample_rate;
    channels_ = metadata->data.stream_info.channels;
    bps_ = metadata->data.stream_info.bits_per_sample;

    switch (bps_) {
        case 16 :

            if (channels_ > 1) {
                format_ = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16; } else { 
                format_ = AL_FORMAT_MONO16; }

            break;
        case 8 :

            if (channels_ > 1) {
                format_ = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8; } else { 
                format_ = AL_FORMAT_MONO8; }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    size_ = (ALuint)(rate_ * channels_ * (bps_ / 8));
    data_.resize(total_samples_); index_ = 0;
} // main
```

Comment: Presumably it's expecting PCM data which is generally interleaved left, right, left, etc.  Do you hear sound from both speakers or only the left?

Comment: Hi again @Retired Ninja. You posted on my last question five hours ago... Ok, so i am hearing sound on the left speaker only until the short sound finishes playing. But after the sound has played in the left speaker, the static (glitchy like sounds) is head in both speakers for short time and than program exits successfully.

Comment: @Retired Ninja So if I made my type say `std::vector<FLAC__int16> data_;` instead of `std::vector<FLAC__int32> data_;` and packed the data into the array left, right, left, etc. Would that work?

Comment: I did work! Now both channels work but there is still that (glitchy like sounds) after the sound has finished playing.

Comment: You test faster than I type. :)  Looking at this [example](https://git.xiph.org/?p=flac.git;a=blob;f=examples/cpp/decode/file/main.cpp;h=72a938b86752baa6729037ef128a214ecb764476;hb=HEAD) they appear to truncate the 32-bit data down to 16 bits when doing the interleaving.  If there's static at the end it sounds like there might be some garbage in the buffer or the size isn't what it expects.

Comment: ^^ lol ok i'll look. What I tried is: struct Data
  {
  
   FLAC__int16 left_;
   FLAC__int16 right_;
  
  }; but was no good...

Comment: I got it to work now!!! I also changed `size_ = (ALuint)(rate_ * channels_ * (bps_ / 8));` into `size_ = total_samples_ * sizeof(Source::Data);`. Source::Data is the `Data { FLAC__int16 left_; FLAC__int16 right_; };` structure which is now the type for mine data as such `std::vector<Source::Data> data_;`. So happy! Thank you @Retired Ninja for all your hints!

Answer (score 0):

A solution which works, was to assagned the below `struct` as the vector data type like so:

```
struct Data
{

    FLAC__int16 channelLeft_;
    FLAC__int16 channelRight_;

};

std::vector<Source::Data> data_;
```

than assign the `size_` like so:

```
size_ = total_samples_ * sizeof(Source::Data);
```

finaly the data loop should now be:

```
for(size_t i(0); i < _frame->header.blocksize; i++) {

    data_[index_].channelLeft_ = _buffer[0][i];
    data_[index_].channelRight_ = _buffer[1][i];

    ++index_;
} // jump
```